# Add keyboard shortcut for a list box

Tags: fonts, listbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am creating an application where I can preview specific text that the user enters in text box in any of the fonts installed on the computer. I have the list of fonts in a list box. I would like to add a shortcut that, when the user presses CTRL+F, it will add that selected font from the list to another list box that contain favorite fonts. I have a button that performs this but I would also like to add a keyboard short cut. The current code I have will add the selected font to the favorites list, but it will also go to the next font name that starts with the letter F. How can I prevent the selected item in the list box from moving to the letter that is pressed as part of the keyboard shortcut?

```
        private void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
            {
                addfavoritesButton_Click(sender, e);
            }
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                saveButton_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question is lacking context.  What language and framework are we talking about here? Is this a browser-based or native application?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you need to prevent the event from continuing to bubble up.  Assuming this is a Windows native app (it's not clear from the question), I think you need to set the `Handled` property of the `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` instance.  That keeps the event from being handled by the default OS handler.